# images not accessible by Vaadin Spring Application

Tags: java, image, spring-boot, vaadin-spring-boot

In the example given here:

https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/application/application-resources.html

the images-folder is put inside the WEB-INF directory of the application.

In my Vaadin Spring application, I do not have a WEB-INF directory, so I put the images folder inside the "resources" folder instead. Here is what the folder structure inside of "src/main/resources" and inside of "target" looks like:

[image]

The problem is that my application cannot access the images there. I always get the same "File not found" exception.

I tried out different path descriptions, among others, the following:

```
VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "images/pic.png"

VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/classes/images/pic.png"

VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/target/classes/images/pic.png"

VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/applicationName/target/classes/images/pic.png"
```

... nothing worked !!

How can I make this images accessible to my Vaadin Spring application?

Comment: Your code suggests that you're trying to load the image as a *File Resource*.  However, if the file is inside the project and on the classpath, don't you want to use a *Class Loader Resource* instead?  Perhaps you can update the question with the code you're using to create the Image component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example you linked to uses `FileResource`. It won't work with jar-packaged resources.

**Preferably**, you can put your images in `src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/{theme}/` and use a ThemeResource :

```
// Image as a file resource
FileResource resource = new ThemeResource("images/image.png");
```

**Alternatively**, put your resource to src/main/resources/ and then access it from classpath:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.png")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, it solved my problem ... in case you have time, please have a look at another question of mine related to this one (actually I thought the answer to this post here would also solve the other problem, but this was not the case so I now created a second post for this other problem): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960392/how-to-create-file-on-server-with-file-path-relative-to-application